# Validation rule for picklist value

Tags: formula, picklist, validation, validation-rule

I am new to saleforce, I want to create a syntax for picklist field role_c is not 'PCG' value then rise message you are not allow to update add to client field.

```
ISPICKVAL(Share_With_User__r.WM_role_c, 'PCG')
```

This syntax for role = 'PCG',

How do you do not equals?

Answer (score 4):

NOT(ISPICKVAL(Share_With_User__r.WM_role_c, 'PCG'))

[image: worflow]

On the right side you can see all the functions and you can see how they can be used. Double-click on them and they will be inserted into the rule criteria for you to modify them.

Check this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=workflow_examples.htm&siteLang=en_US) as well for more examples on how to build workflow rules. Also explanation and examples of all functions can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US)

Comment: Hi Mihai, thanks for your response, however, when I tested to add record the message not pop up but I just got freeze and the save button is not working

Comment: I'm not sure in what context you use the negation. Also this might not be the whole workflow rule that you use and I don't know what you are trying to achieve